Bots in Database although installed re-captcha and blocked by gmail
We are having issues with our deliverability for our double opt-in emails for some of our webshops. For gmail most of our emails blockbounce.
The error message we are getting is as follows:
5.0.0 (SMTP reply matched bounce-rcpt pattern rule); smtp;450 4.2.1 The user you are trying to contact is receiving mail at a rate that prevents additional messages from being delivered. Please resend your message at a later time. If the user is able to receive mail at that time, your message will be delivered. For more information, go to Limits for sending & getting mail.
We have contacted our Email Service Provider and they said that most likely we are having issues with list bombing and the solution would be to install re-captcha in our forms.
We already have Re-Captcha on our forms.
So I am not sure how to proceed here. Goole Re-Captcha is letting users through but at the same time we are getting blocked from Gmail.
Could you please advise us how to proceed?
